# How do I create a dropdown menu without using OptionMenu for tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, optionmenu, tkinter.optionmenu

Whenever I run my code, there's a 50/50 chance it crashes when my dropdown menu is clicked, coming up with a "Segmentation fault: 11" on vscode, I've also tried on pycharm.
there is no apparent reason that this code shouldn't work, so I would like to know if there is a different way to create a dropdown menu, thanks!
Code in question:

options = [
"AM",
"PM"
]

```
variable = StringVar()
variable.set(options[0])
am_pm = OptionMenu(root, variable, *options)
```

Comment: Crashes how? Is there an error?

Comment: Are you aware of the [ttk.Combobox](https://tkdocs.com/pyref/ttk_combobox.html) widget?